# How can I get console input mid-build in Shake?

Tags: shake-build-system

For various unfortunate reasons, part of my build requires root privileges. I'm trying to use `sudo` for this:

```
cmd_ "sudo other_script.sh" [input] [output]
```

However, presumably because of how Shake handles console input/output, I cannot actually enter my password when `sudo` runs. I have tried passing `WithStderr False` to `cmd_`, as well as setting `shakeLineBuffering=False`, to no avail.

What is the correct way to allow a command to prompt for user input? If such a thing does not exist, is there another good way to do something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is `InheritStdin` which ensures that the standard input is given to the process, so you can actually type in the password. You might also need to set `EchoStderr` or `EchoStdout` so you can see the password prompt.

Alternatively, you don't have to use `cmd`. Within Shake, `cmd` is optimised for an ergonomic way of running commands with tight integration. But it's easy enough to use the default `System.Process` module if you need more control, for example:

```
liftIO $ System.Process.system "sudo script input output"
```